# Question how to convert mongodb's commands to Bson in Golang

Tags: json, mongodb, go, mongodb-query, bson

This is collection list

```
{
    _id : autoIncrement
    "P_NAME" : "Name",
    "P_LIST" : [
        {
            _id : autoIncrement
            "P_TYPE" : "HELL",
            "P_POOL" : "Not Use"
        }
    ]
}
```

I used this command when I used it in MongoDB.

```
db.P.find({},{"P_LIST": {$elemMatch: {_id:2}}, _id: 0})
```

And similarly in Golang, I tried to search for such a condition, but it did not work.

```
collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.M{bson.M{}, bson.M{"P_LIST":bson.M{"$elemMatch":bson.M{"_id":2}}, bson.M{"_id": 0}}})
```

How can Golang use the Find command with conditions and filters like MongoDB?

Comment: For one thing you should not use `P_LIST` in one case and `POLICY_LIST` in another. Concerning the rest, what is your problem? What doesn't work? As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Oh! I find a mistake and made a correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `Find` wrong, you pass the filter and projection into Find's filter param.

```golang
func (coll *Collection) Find(ctx context.Context, filter interface{},
    opts ...*options.FindOptions) (*Cursor, error)
```

Try doing it like this:

```golang
collection.Find(
    context.TODO(),
    nil,
    options.Find().SetProjection(bson.M{
        "P_LIST": bson.M{
            "$elemMatch": bson.M{"_id": 2},
            "_id":        0,
        },
    })
)
```

See more details about `Find` [here](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.Find)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried to do this, but `options.Find () SetProjection (bson.M {bson.M {" P_LIST ": bson.M {" $ elemMatch ": bson.M {" _id ": 2} }}, Bson. M {"_ id"}})` `A missing key in map literal` error is displayed at the relevant part. Now I want to know why there is such an error.

Comment: @SangGeol I've updated the answer, there was a typo on the map I passed to `SetProjection`